# How to get data of last 6 hours using sqllite

Tags: sqlite

Code:

```
.mode column
.width 40 20 20 6 10 90
.headers off
select name, datetime("start time","unixepoch","localtime"), datetime("end time","unixepoch","localtime"), "end time"-"start time", "completion status", "failed clients list"
from  "savegroup job"
where datetime("end time","unixepoch","localtime") >= datetime("now", "-6 hours")
and "completion status" like "%failed%";
```

The `>= datetime("now", "-6 hours")` does not work.

I need to get the last input data from the last 6 hours.

Thanks

Comment: Show your table definition and some sample rows from it, and what results you want from that sample. (spaces in column and table names? Eww.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue is very likely that the values in the **start time** and **end time** columns are not saved in the correct format. That is for the **unixepoch** modifer to apply then the values MUST be in DDDDDDDDDD format.

As per :-

> The "unixepoch" modifier (11) only works if it immediately follows a
>   timestring in the DDDDDDDDDD format. This modifier causes the
>   DDDDDDDDDD to be interpreted not as a Julian day number as it normally
>   would be, but as Unix Time - the number of seconds since 1970. If the
>   "unixepoch" modifier does not follow a timestring of the form
>   DDDDDDDDDD which expresses the number of seconds since 1970 or if
>   other modifiers separate the "unixepoch" modifier from prior
>   DDDDDDDDDD then the behavior is undefined. For SQLite versions before
>   3.16.0 (2017-01-02), the "unixepoch" modifier only works for dates between 0000-01-01 00:00:00 and 5352-11-01 10:52:47 (unix times of
>   -62167219200 through 106751991167).

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - Date And Time Functions - Modifiers](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

For example consider the following (see comments) :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'savegroup job';
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'savegroup job' (name TEXT,'start time' TEXT, 'end time' TEXT, 'completion status' TEXT);
INSERT INTO 'savegroup job' VALUES

  -- store values in DDDDDDDDDD format
    ('Name001',strftime('%s','2018-01-01 10:30'),strftime('%s','2018-01-01 12:30'),'this failed'),
    ('Name002',strftime('%s','2018-02-01 10:30'),strftime('%s','2018-02-01 12:30'),'this failed'),
    ('Name003',strftime('%s','2018-03-01 10:30'),strftime('%s','2018-03-01 12:30'),'this failed'),
    ('Name004',strftime('%s','now'),strftime('%s','now','+6 hours'),'this failed'),
    ('Name005',strftime('%s','now','+3 hours'),strftime('%s','now','+14 hours'),'this failed'),

    -- store values in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format 
    ('Name006','2018-01-01 10:30','2018-01-01 12:30','this failed'),
    ('Name007','2018-01-01 10:30','2018-01-01 12:30','this failed'),
    ('Name008','2018-01-01 10:30','2018-01-01 12:30','this failed'),
    ('Name009',datetime('now'),datetime('now','+6 hours'),'this failed'),
    ('Name010',datetime('now','+3 hours'),datetime('now','+14 hours'),'this failed')
;
-- Show all data
SELECT * FROM 'savegroup job';

-- The query from the question
select name, datetime("start time","unixepoch","localtime"), datetime("end time","unixepoch","localtime"), "end time"-"start time", "completion status", "failed clients list"
from  "savegroup job"
where datetime("end time","unixepoch","localtime") >= datetime("now", "-6 hours")
and "completion status" like "%failed%";
```

### Results

#### All data :-

[image]

#### Your Query (it does work if the values are store in the correct format) :-

[image]

### Handle data as currently stored

Assuming that the issue is that columns **start time** and **end time** do have values store as in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format (rows where name is Name006 - Name010) then the following query would work :-

```
-- Modified query from the question
SELECT name, 
    datetime("start time"), 
    datetime("end time"),
    strftime('%s',datetime("end time"))-strftime('%s',datetime("start time")), 
    "completion status", 
    "failed clients list"
FROM  "savegroup job"
-- where strftime('%s',"end time","unixepoch","localtime") >= strftime('%s',"now", "-6 hours") and "completion status" like "%failed%";
WHERE strftime('%s',"end time") >= strftime('%s',datetime('now','-6 hours'))
    AND "completion status" LIKE '%failed%'
;
```

resulting in :-

[image]